# Serilog enriched properties not being sent across HTTP Sink

Tags: sql-server, http, asp.net-core, serilog

I'm using Serilog HTTP sink from a web service to send logs to a different logging service. That logging service then uses the MSSQLServer Serilog sink to write to the DB.

I'm wondering about adding enriched properties from the initial service though. I'm using `Enrich.WithProperty("x", "y")` from the initial calling service (in Startup.cs), but those properties don't seem to get sent to the logging service.

If I call `Enrich.WithProperty("x", "y")` on the logging service itself, I see those values get added to the DB (I have a custom column for "x", and it is populated with "y" in this case), but I need those properties sent from the initial service

How do I pass those enriched properties (or any other properties for that matter) across the HTTP sink for logging on the other end?

Thanks!

Comment: How does the service that consumes the log is rewriting the logs to the DB? - I would guess that's where properties are being lost, not on the sending side - i.e. the HTTP Sink definitely sends the properties across. You can check with [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or a similar tool

Comment: @C.AugustoProiete I'm using the MSSQLSERVER sink (https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http) to write to the DB. Looking into what is sent on the wire now.

Comment: The question is "how" you are writing the logs to the SQLServer sink on point B. If I understand correctly, you have a controller on point B receiving the JSON sent by the HTTP sink from point A. Once you receive the JSON, how exactly are you writing to Serilog? My guess is that the loss of data happens there - i.e. you might be discarding the properties you received instead of adding them to the log context of point B

Comment: @C.AugustoProiete thanks for your help. Indeed, I took a closer look at how I was deserializing the information on the receiving side, and I wasn't properly mapping the properties to something, so they were being sent on the wire (as you suggested), but I wasn't retrieving them properly. Now I am pulling them out of the log info I receive and adding them with PushProperty and I see them in the DB now.

Comment: Great to hear! I've added my comment as an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66270019/211672)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a controller on point `B` receiving a JSON sent via the HTTP sink from point `A`. Once you receive the JSON, the properties are present.

In order to write the properties to the new sink, you'll need to read the properties from the JSON and [add them to the `LogContext`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment#the-logcontext).

[image: Serilog LogContext]

Comment: Wow, thank you @C.AugustoProiete for helping out with this. Your answer got my vote. Have a great weekend!